# SVN upgrade 1.6.6 to 1.8.8

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We recently upgrade Ubuntu 10.04.4 to 14.04.1.
Therefore, SVN 1.6.6 in Ubuntu 10.04.4  and 1.8.8 in the updated version.

After research, we use the upgrade common:

```
svnadmin upgrade 
Repository lock acquired.
Please wait; upgrading the repository may take some time...

Upgrade completed
```

**Wish to know the we are on right track or not.**

We need to know what should do more for SVN server site.

We still use TortoiseSVN 1.8.2.

We really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Are you asking if you should use svnadmin to upgrade your server or are you asking how to upgrade your local repositories using Tortoise? Both?

Comment: How could we know which repositories  on servers has done for upgrade? We have 1 project for 1 repository. Is it possible to upgrade all repositories. Why the developer need to upgrade local repositories using Tortoise?